# Append Azure Service Principal SAML notification emails instead of replacement

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-service-principal

Unable to append the notification email addresses on separate fields in Azure Service principal's SAML certificate notification email field.

I've tried the below; however, it adds to the existing notification email but not on separate notification email fields in Azure.

[Notification email fields in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuASP.png)

$ServicePrincipalIDs = Get-Content C:\temp\spIds.txt
Foreach($ServicePrincipalID in $ServicePrincipalIDs)

```
{

    $SP1 = Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId "$ServicePrincipalID" 
    $SPDisplayName = $SP1.AppDisplayName
    
   
 
    $SP1NotificationDetails = $SP1.NotificationEmailAddresses += "hello@abc.com"


    Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId "$ServicePrincipalID" -NotificationEmailAddresses "$SP1NotificationDetails"
```

}

Can you please let me know how do I append the email addresses instead of replacing the emails.

Comment: You need a semicolon between each email address.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to have it added to the existing notification email addresses. I am fetching the existing one and adding an additional email to them. But the whole list is appearing on one field.

Comment: Does this line really make any sense and where are you adding the semicolon? $SP1NotificationDetails = $SP1.NotificationEmailAddresses += "hello@abc.com"

Comment: A small correction to that line. It is   $SP1NotificationDetails += $SP1.NotificationEmailAddresses + "hello@abc.com". There is no "=" sign ( typo ).
It basically picks the existing notification email addresses, appends "hello@abc.com" and stores these values in $SPNotificationDetails variable to be used in Update-MGServicePrincipal

Comment: You are still missing the semicolon

Comment: The list is added on same field even if I add semicolon.
 $SP1NotificationDetails += $SP1.NotificationEmailAddresses +  ";" +"hello@abc.com"
Correct me if this is not the intended one.

Comment: Why would it be on a different field?

Comment: hope you didn't get my question, I want the email addresses in Azure AD to be populated on separate fields as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple notification email addresses you can pass a simple string array:

```
[System.String[]]$NotificationEMailAddress = @("john.doe@example.com", "jane.smith@example.com", "bob.jones@example.com")
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All"
[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]$samlApplicationsArray = @()
$samlApplications = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "PreferredSingleSignOnMode eq 'saml'"
    
foreach ($samlApp in $samlApplications)
{
    Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $($samlApp.Id) -NotificationEmailAddresses $NotificationEMailAddress
}
    
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

It took me almost an hour to figure out what was wrong :-D